# Getting error while trying to run ./configure --prefix=/tools so to install systemc

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gcc, c++, configure

I am trying to install systemc-2.3.3 on ubuntu 18.04LTS. Previously I tried with 20LTS that didn't work for some reason.I am following these instructions :[Installation of SystemC-2.3.3](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pP_sRk4h0lplZ6D5stfvQwdGgZ_8ARHglmN8s-hNVjM/edit?usp=sharing). I am a newbie and never install any software on ubuntu.
When I entered the commands I was getting following error:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking whether make supports nested variables... no
checking how to create a pax tar archive... gnutar
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) no
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/radhe/tools':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I cannot understand my configure file. Link to configure file is :[configure file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t-kEb26HoCmxK4U7iclOk7-FMJvdqGWn/view?usp=sharing)
Please Help.

Comment: Is there a C++ compiler installed on your system? if not, install `g++` and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install needed build tools by

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and then compile the application.